# Go - Encode struct fields with the same tag

Tags: xml, go, encoding, struct

I am dealing with an API that is expecting XML that is generally formatted like so.

```
<receiver>
    <receiver_type>test</receiver_type>
    <hostnames>http://posttestserver.com</hostnames>
    <credentials>
      <credential>
        <name>app-id</name>
        <value>1234</value>
        <safe>true</safe>
      </credential>
      <credential>
        <name>app-secret</name>
        <value>5678</value>
      </credential>
    </credentials>
  </receiver>
```

Therefore, in my Go code, I made these structs to use in my functions and  marshal into the XML structure. Note that different receivers can have different sets of credentials.

```
type Receiver1 struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name             `xml:"receiver"`
    ReceiverType string               `xml:"receiver_type"`
    HostNames    string               `xml:"hostnames"`
    Credentials  Receiver1Credentials `xml:"credentials"`
}

type Receiver2 struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name             `xml:"receiver"`
    ReceiverType string               `xml:"receiver_type"`
    HostNames    string               `xml:"hostnames"`
    Credentials  Receiver2Credentials `xml:"credentials"`
}

type Receiver1Credentials struct {
    AppID     Credential `xml:"credential"`
    AppSecret Credential `xml:"credential"`
}

type Receiver2Credentials struct {
    UserName Credential `xml:"credential"`
    Password Credential `xml:"credential"`
    AppID    Credential `xml:"credential"`
}

type Credential struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name"`
    Value string `xml:"value"`
    Safe  bool   `xml:"safe"`
}
```

However this produces runtime errors along the lines of `Receiver1Credentials field "AppID" with tag "credential" conflicts with field "AppSecret" with tag "credential"` meaning that I can't directly tag the Credentials fields the same thing. I've tried using a field `XMLName xml.Name xml:"credential"` (like on the Receiver structs) on the Credential struct, but it gets overwritten by the tag on the Credentials structs. Does anyone know how I could work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Marshal the data into xml, you can simply create a simple receiver struct, initialize it, and call `xml.Marshal(...)`.

(Note that to nest `credential` into `credentials`, explicit xml tag needs to be associated with the fields)

```
type Receiver struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name     `xml:"receiver"`
    ReceiverType string       `xml:"receiver_type"`
    HostNames    string       `xml:"hostnames"`
    Credentials  []Credential `xml:"credentials>credential"` // necessary to allow tag nesting
}

type Credential struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name"`
    Value string `xml:"value"`
    Safe  bool   `xml:"safe,omitempty"` // omitempty does not include the tag if if it's empty
}
```

Now you can simply initialize a `Receiver` and marshal it into xml:

```
r := &Receiver{
        ReceiverType: "test",
        HostNames: "http://posttestserver.com",
        Credentials: []Credential{
            Credential{"app-id", "1234", true},
            Credential{"app-secret", "5678", false},
        },
    }
    a, _ := xml.MarshalIndent(r, "", "  ") // a is []byte containing xml encoded data
```

(working example: https://play.golang.org/p/JZcUUK9P1f)

*Original answer - method to unmarshal the above xml into receiver*

If you can avoid parsing the xml data directly into `Receiver[12]Credentials`, you can unmarshal the xml data into a much simpler structure (`Receiver` and `Credential` above) using the following method:

```
receiver := &Receiver{}
xml.Unmarshal(xmlDataByteSlice, receiver)
```

This would store all the `Credential` objects in `receiver.Credentials` above:

```
fmt.Println(receiver.Credentials)
// [{app-id 1234 true} {app-secret 5678 false}]
```

You can then perhaps use a `switch case` on `receiver,Credential.Name` to initialize `Receiver[12]Credentials` accordingly.

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/jq3BrxKVo-

Comment: I didn't make this clear in my post, but I was looking to marshal the XML not unmarshal. Apologies.

Comment: To Marshal the data into xml, you can simply create a `receiver` struct, initialize it, and call `xml.Marshal(...)`: https://play.golang.org/p/JZcUUK9P1f or am I missing something here?

Comment: That does work, you are correct. I'm going to mark your answer correct, but for the sake of keeping the question and answer consistent could you change your answer to show the marshaling rather than the unmarshaling?